# Combining Parallel randomForest in R - Foreach (DoSNOW)

Tags: r, foreach, random-forest, parallel-foreach

Microsoft R Open 3.2.3 - Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - 64-bit, 8 Cores and lots of Memory.

Im executing randomForest using 4 cores, everything works fine (about 4x faster than single thread) except that I cant combine the results.

I've tried twice with different codes:

1) I run the foreach and than combine the result later:

```
library(randomForest)
library(doSNOW)

cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
classif<-foreach(ntreeRF=rep(25,4), .packages="randomForest") %dopar% {
 randomForest(x=my_df,y=my_df[,answer],mtry=10,nodeSize=50,ntree=ntreeRF)
}
classif_comb<-combine(classif[[1]],classif[[2]],classif[[3]],classif[[4]])
#also tried: classif_comb<-do.call('combine',classif), but classif is a 'list' object
stop(cl)
#class of classif[[n]] is randomForest
```

2) Here I tried to use the .combine parameter in foreach function

```
library(randomForest)
library(doSNOW)

cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
classif<-foreach(ntreeRF=rep(25,4), .packages="randomForest",.combine=combine, .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
 randomForest(x=my_df,y=my_df[,answer],mtry=10,nodeSize=50,ntree=ntreeRF)
}
stop(cl)
```

In both I received the same error message:
"combine() depricated due to naming conflict renamed consolidate()"

When I run the "same" code in my laptop, using iris data, everything works fine.

Also, when I load doSNOW library I receive a warning message: "built under R version 3.3.1".. but the combine() function belongs to randomForest Package, so I think that is not the problem..

Any ideas?!

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you have other packages loaded in the workspace? Some package seemed to have tried to resolve an issue, I know neither of the loaded package has. Also, you can use `multicombine = TRUE` which will make things a bit faster.

Comment: The current package `Hmisc` has a `consolidate` function. Does it appear in `search()`? Which version `packageVersion("Hmisc")`?

Comment: @NJBurgo Just found the problem thanks to your suggestion about look other packages loaded in the environment! My coworker loaded the library(e1071) to use other model.. I still don't know exactly what happened but this package comes with some "deprecated" function that probably messed things up! I just loaded in a new environment the 4 randomForest objects, the library(randomForest) and used the combine() function and everything worked fine!! Thanks again!! (btw, fyi: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf)

Comment: @NJBurgo  My mistake! Actually, there was a function loading other lots of functions (including Hmisc)! Once Hmisc is loaded, a message comes up: "Attacking package: 'Hmisc' The following object is masked from 'package:randomForest': combine'".. But I still don't get why that happens, could you explain?! And how to go around this problem if I need to load Hmisc anyway? Thank you!! EDIT(packageVersion("Hmisc"): 3.17.1

Comment: The simple answer is that there are 7000+ packages on CRAN now and not enough wortds for all the functions that might need to exist! The solution is: 1) load the packages in a different order (`randomForest` after the package that loads `Hmisc`), or 2) use `randomForest::combine` (note the `::`) which uses combine from the randomForest namespace.

Comment: @NJBurgo Awesome! Thank you again!